# ImportError: No Module Named bs4 (MacOS)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I run my script I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I tried to install `BeautifulSoup4` using the following commands but apparently it's already installed:

```
MyMac:Test user$ pip3 install bs4
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bs4) (4.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (1.9.4)

MyMac:Test user$ pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
Requirement already satisfied: BeautifulSoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from BeautifulSoup4) (1.9.4)
```

I get the same error if I run the script again

Comment: are you sure you are running the script with the correct python version you installed the library `>3`?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: in PyCharm it works well, when I try to run it from console it gives me this error